# Unable to initialize 'javax.el.ExpressionFactory'. Check that you have the EL dependencies on the classpath

Tags: java, dropwizard, java-17

I am currently upgrading my project from Java 8 to Java 18, along with upgraded bunch of libraries like Apache Spark, Dropwizard, Hibernate, Swagger etc. Right now, my application is coming up in my local however when I try to deploy to servers, service is not coming up and throwing `javax.validation.ValidationException`.

Here is the full stacktrace:

```
javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000183: Unable to initialize 'javax.el.ExpressionFactory'. Check that you have the EL dependencies on the classpath, or use ParameterMessageInterpolator instead
    at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.buildExpressionFactory(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.<init>(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.AbstractConfigurationImpl.getDefaultMessageInterpolator(AbstractConfigurationImpl.java:573)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.AbstractConfigurationImpl.getDefaultMessageInterpolatorConfiguredWithClassLoader(AbstractConfigurationImpl.java:822)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.AbstractConfigurationImpl.getMessageInterpolator(AbstractConfigurationImpl.java:483)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl.<init>(ValidatorFactoryImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.buildValidatorFactory(HibernateValidator.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.AbstractConfigurationImpl.buildValidatorFactory(AbstractConfigurationImpl.java:433)
    at io.dropwizard.jersey.validation.Validators.newValidatorFactory(Validators.java:26)
    at io.dropwizard.setup.Bootstrap.<init>(Bootstrap.java:67)
    at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:86)
    at com.company.Service.main(Service.java:554)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at javassist.Loader.run(Loader.java:328)
    at com.company.custom.metadata.ServiceRun.run(AServiceRun.java:148)
    at com.company.api.PartnerServiceRun.main(PartnerServiceRun.java:10)
```

I checked about this on Stackoverflow and some users suggested trying new versions of `Javax.el` libraries but I am still having issue with `3.0.0` and `3.0.1-b08` . Any suggestions or pointers are appreciated. Thanks

**Trail 1**: Didn't work

```
'javax.el:javax.el-api:3.0.0',
'org.glassfish:javax.el:3.0.0',
```

**Trail 2**: Didn't work

```
'javax.el:javax.el-api:3.0.1-b06',
'org.glassfish:javax.el:3.0.1-b08',
```

Comment: This is a guess, but try using the jakarta EL API instead of the javax. (jakarta.el-api and expressly)
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.el/jakarta.el-api/5.0.1
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.expressly/expressly/5.0.0

Comment: @ThiagoHenriqueHupner Thanks, adding Expressly instead of `org.glassfish:javax.el` helped me to resolve the issue. It might be worth adding this as an answer to the question.